# PDO- Delete entire row

Tags: php, database, pdo, delete-row

I'm trying to delete an entire row in a database table. Here I want to delete the row if `$token` and `$user_id` is matched.But my code is not working.

```
<?php
 $delete_rt_string = $this->db_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM rt_strings WHERE rt_string = :rt_string AND user_id = :user_id ");
 $delete_rt_string->bindValue(':rt_string', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $delete_rt_string->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $delete_rt_string->execute();
?>
```

If I use this the code below it works perfectly.

```
<?php
 $delete_rt_string = $this->db_connection->prepare("DELETE FROM rt_strings WHERE rt_string = :rt_string ");
 $delete_rt_string->bindValue(':rt_string', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $delete_rt_string->execute();
?>
```

I don't know why `AND` condition is not working.Or am I miss something?

Comment: Have you checked that `$user_id` is getting correctly set in a way that matches data in the database?

Comment: yeah..var_dump($user_id) returns its value.

Comment: Does the SQL return any errors? What does it return if you `var_dump()` the `$delete_rt_string`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using alone `user_id = :user_id` condition and check if its working, If not then there must be some problem in the `user_id` value.